# Explode unique tags values from specific column of blogs table

Tags: php, laravel, explode, laravel-query-builder

I have table called Blogs in which i have tags where user can store their own custom multiple tags .

```
Blogs Table :
Id
Name
Tags
```

I store them using implode function as :

```
$tags = implode(',', $tags);
```

Now i want to explode all values i tired that but didn't succeded also i want to explode these values as unique not repeated one .

Here is a query i tried

```
$blogs_tag = \App\Models\Blog::select('tags')->where('status' , '=' ,'active')->get();
$tags = explode("," ,$blogs_tag);

@foreach ($tags as $tag)            
  <a class="item active" href="#">{{$tag}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Right now it gives folowing output when i DD single value:

```
  "[{"tags":"new"}"
```

Comment: `$blogs_tag` is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, not an array. Please look into [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to see how this should be properly done at the model level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments;

```php
$blogs_tag = Blog::select('tags')->where('status' , '=' ,'active')->get();
```

Returns a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) of `Blog` models, not all the `tags` for all `Blog` models, so in your `@foreach` loop, you're not looping all the `tags` but rather all the `Blog` models returned from your query.

An option if you want just the `tags`, you could loop your results. As an example:

```php
$tags = [];

$blog_tags->each(function ($blog) use (&$tags) {
    $tags = array_merge($tags, explode(',', $blog->tags));
});
```

The above assumes you want all the tags as a single array, but basically it loops over your `$blog_tags` results gets the `$tags` attribute and uses `explode` to split the comma separated string before combining it with any previous iterations in the `$tags` array.

To remove the duplicates, you can use [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Thanks @peppermintology for the answer it worked !!